Show that $\int_0^{1/2}\log(n(\arcsin x-\arcsin(x-1/n)))\mathrm dx$ converges to $\frac12-\frac14\log(27/4)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{1/2}\log\left(n\left(\arcsin x-\arcsin\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right)\mathrm dx=\frac12-\frac14\log\frac{27}{4}$.

Here is the graph of $y=\log\left(n\left(\arcsin x-\arcsin\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right)$ for $0<x<\frac12$ with $n=10^5$.

This claim has numerical evidence, but Wolfram does not evaluate the limit, indefinite integral, nor definite integral. I'm at a loss of what to do.

Context (optional reading)
In a semicircle with diameter $na$, draw chords of lengths $a,2a,3a,\dots,na$ that meet at one of the endpoints of the semicircle.
Here is an example with $n=6$.

Consider the $n$ arcs between neighboring chord endpoints.
Numerical investigation led me to the following claim: If $a=\frac{3\sqrt3}{2e}$ then as $n\to\infty$ the product of the arc lengths converges to unity. This claim is equivalent to the claim about the integral in this question.
Edit
I made a calculation mistake (in one step I used the diameter instead of the radius). So it is not true that "If $a=\frac{3\sqrt3}{2e}$ then as $n\to\infty$ the product of the arc lengths converges to unity" (and that claim is not equivalent to the claim in this question).
After correcting my mistake, I have: If $a=\frac{2}{e}$ then the product of arc lengths is $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{2n}{e}\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\right)$, which seems to converge to $1.225\dots$ (I ask about the limit here).
Anyway, I still learned something from the answers to my question.

By the Mean Value theorem, since $\frac{d}{dx}(\arcsin(x)) = (1-x^2)^{-1/2},$
$$n(\arcsin(x) - \arcsin(x-1/n)) = (1-(c_n(x))^2)^{-1/2}$$
where $c_n(x) \in (x-1/n, x)$.
Therefore, your limit may be written
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{1/2} \log\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-(c_n(x))^2}}\right)\,dx$$
Now, for $n \geq 2$, the integrand is uniformly bounded by $\frac12\log(4/3)$, so by the dominated convergence theorem, we may bring the limit inside the integral.  By continuity, we can also bring the limit inside the function to $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n(x) = x$.
That is, the limit is equal to
$$\int_0^{1/2} \log\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\,dx$$
which can be evaluated using elementary means to give $\frac12 - \frac14\log(27/4)$.

If anyone is concerned about the measurability of $c_n$, it might be useful to note that the measurability of $c_n$ itself doesn't matter, since we never integrate it.  Rather, the integrands are all known and continuous: $$\log\left(1/\sqrt{1-(c_n(x))^2}\right) = \log\Big(n(\arcsin(x)-\arcsin(x-1/n))\Big)$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(1/\sqrt{1-(c_n(x))^2}\right) = \log\left(1/\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$$
(That said, I'm fairly certain it can be proven every $c_n$ may be chosen to be continuous, even though for our current purposes that's unnecessary)

Thanks! I've written an answer that shows another way to get to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, but I'm not sure if it's rigorous. What do you think?

@Dan The only issue I'm running into in your solution is the final "Therefore".  We need some sort of theorem that says that the convergence $n(f(x)-f(x-1/n)) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} f'(x)$ is nice enough that we can bring the limit inside the integral.  It might be that the boundedness of $\log(f'(x))$ on $(0,1/2)$ is enough, but I can't remember right now.

Thanks, I'll think about it.

Since
$$\sin\Bigg(\sin ^{-1}(x)-\sin ^{-1}\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)\Bigg)=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{n}+x
   \sqrt{1-\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2}-x\sqrt{1-x^2} $$ building, from inside to outside the series expansion of the integrand, this boils down to the integral of
$$-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(1-x^2\right)+\frac{x}{2 n
   \left(x^2-1\right)}+\frac{5 x^2+4}{24 n^2
   \left(x^2-1\right)^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) $$ which gives
$$I_n=\frac{1}{4} \left(2-\log \left(\frac{27}{4}\right)\right)-\frac 1 {4n} \log \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)+\frac{6-\coth ^{-1}(2)}{48 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) $$
For $n=10$, this very truncated expansion gives $0.0165579$ to be compared to $0.0165051$.

I think a better way to proceed would be to show that the sequence of functions $f_n:x \mapsto n*(\mbox{arcsin}(x) - \mbox{arcsin}(x-\dfrac{1}{n}))$ converges uniformly on the segment $[0; \dfrac{1}{2}]$ towards $f : x \mapsto \left ( \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \right )$. As the MVT yields a function $c_n$ that we know little about, (is it integrable?), this seems cleaner to me.
Take $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ x\in [0; \dfrac{1}{2}]$. The Taylor-Lagrange with integral rest formula yields:
$\mbox{arcsin}(x-\dfrac{1}{n}) = \mbox{arcsin}(x) - \dfrac{1}{n\sqrt{1-x^2}} - \displaystyle\int_{x}^{x-\frac{1}{n}} \dfrac{(x-\frac{1}{n}-t)*t}{(\sqrt{1-t^2})^3} \,dt $
So : $\mid f(x) - f_n(x) \mid \leq n*\displaystyle\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x} \dfrac{\mid x-\frac{1}{n}-t\mid*t}{(\sqrt{1-t^2})^3} \,dt \leq \dfrac {n}{n} * \displaystyle\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x} \dfrac{t}{(\sqrt{1-t^2})^3} dt$
The function $g : t \mapsto \dfrac{t}{(\sqrt{1-t^2})^3}$ being continuous on the compact $[-\dfrac{1}{2} ; \dfrac{1}{2}]$, it is bounded by a constant $M$ on this compact.
Finally: $\mid f(x) - f_n(x) \mid \leq \dfrac{M}{n}$.
And thus $ \mid \mid f-f_n\mid \mid_{ \infty, [0; \frac{1}{2}]} \longrightarrow 0$.
To show that $\mbox{ln}(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $[0; \dfrac{1}{2}]$ towards  $ \mbox{ln}(f)$, one could invoke the uniform continuity of ln on the compact $[\dfrac{1}{2}; \dfrac{4}{2}]$, which is where the images of $f$ and $f_n$ are included into for big enough $n$.
Thus, because of the uniform convergence on the segment:
$ \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \mbox{ln}(n*(\mbox{arcsin}(x) - \mbox{arcsin}(x-\dfrac{1}{n})))dx \longrightarrow \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \mbox{ln}\left (\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right )dx $

Using $\arcsin u = \int_0^u \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}\,\mathrm{d} t$ for $-1 < u < 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &n(\arcsin x - \arcsin (x - 1/n))\\
 ={}& 
 n\left(\int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}\,\mathrm{d} t
 - \int_0^{x-1/n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}\,\mathrm{d} t\right)\\
 ={}& n\int_{x-1/n}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}\,\mathrm{d} t\\
 ={}& \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- (x - y/n)^2}}\,\mathrm{d} y
\end{align*}
where we use the integral substitution $t = x - y/n$.
Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^{1/2} \ln[n(\arcsin x - \arcsin (x - 1/n))]\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 ={}& \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^{1/2} \ln\left[\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- (x - y/n)^2}}\,\mathrm{d} y\right]\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 ={}& \int_0^{1/2} \ln\left[\int_0^1 \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1- (x-y/n)^2}}\,\mathrm{d} y\right]\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 ={}& \int_0^{1/2} \ln\left[\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- x^2}}\,\mathrm{d} y\right]\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 ={}& \int_0^{1/2} \ln\left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- x^2}}\right]\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 ={}& \frac12 - \frac14\ln \frac{27}{4}.
\end{align*}
(Note: Alternatively, we can use $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1- (x - y/n)^2}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- x^2}} + O(1/n)$.)
